# What is the difference between hot reload, hot restart, and full restart?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the difference between hot reload, hot restart, and full restart in Flutter and does web support them too?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Hot Reload:

- Hot reload loads code changes into the VM and re-builds the widget tree, preserving the app state; it doesn’t rerun `main()` or `initState()`.

  **For IntelliJ or Android Studio**: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

  **For VSCode**: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

#### Hot Restart:

- Hot restart loads code changes into the VM, and restarts the Flutter app, losing the app state.

  **For IntelliJ or Android Studio**: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

  **For VSCode**: <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

#### Full Restart:

- Full restart restarts the iOS, Android, or web app. This takes longer because it also recompiles the Java / Kotlin / ObjC / Swift code. On the web, it also restarts the Dart Development Compiler. There is no specific keyboard shortcut for this; you need to stop and start the run configuration.

Flutter web currently supports hot restart but not hot reload.

Comment: 1 upvote is not enough for this answer.